# Change date and time formate in PHP [advance way]

Tags: php, html, date, time, formatting

I can change the date and time but I issue is I save my date and time in database in this format `Thursday 09th of July 2020 12:24:23 PM` so I want to convert this in `d-m-Y OR d-m-Y H:i:s` Please help me how to I make this I search this related thread on stackoverflow but I couldn't achieve that ..

current I have tried this below code..

```
<?php
    $orgDate = "Thursday 09th of July 2020 12:24:23 PM";
    $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($orgDate));
    echo "New date format is: ". $newDate. " (MM-DD-YYYY)";
?>
```

RESPONSE: `New date format is: 01-01-1970 (MM-DD-YYYY)`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would make sure the date is being saved in simplier format to database (`DATETIME`), then it's more accessible and even easy to use in database query when comparing dates etc.

But if you have no choice, this should do:

```
$orgDate = "Thursday 09th of July 2020 12:24:23 PM";
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('l dS * F Y h:i:s A', $orgDate);
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

DateTime parameters are explained in documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php